In Europe, are you allowed to enter an intersection on red light in order to allow emergency vehicles to pass?
I've seen a video where cars are stopped at a red light, when an emergency vehicle approaches from behind with sirens on. Emergency vehicle picks the lane with the least traffic, which only has one car in it. Since the car is stopped at the stop line, they cannot move out of the way without entering the intersection (i.e. running the red light), and therefore doesn't move until the light turns green.
Are the driver's actions legal in this situation, or is the driver required by law to enter the intersection on red in order to make way for the emergency vehicle?

So far, I've managed to find an answers for two countries:
In the UK, Rule 219 of the highway code states that you must comply with all traffic laws while making way for emergency vehicles, so driver's refusal to run the red in order to let the emergency vehicle pass would be legal in the UK.
In Slovenia, the relevant law (ZPrCP) requires drivers to make way for emergency vehicles with emergency lights on (section 101), but the section has no paragraph specifically allowing drivers to break other traffic laws while doing so. This suggests that driver's actions would be the thing you're legally required to do in such circumstances in Slovenia.
Finding information for other European countries is proving a bit harder for me due to language barrier.

In this situation, have the emergency responders given the driver an explicit instruction over the loudspeaker, or have they merely honked meaningfully at the driver, or are they simply waiting for the driver to take the initiative?

I am skeptical that Rule 219 in the U.K. would, in fact, be enforced in that manner in this situation described.

@ohwilleke For a light-controlled junction with automatic cameras, it absolutely would be enforced and the driver would have to make a defence, which magistrates may or may not accept.

In the UK, you can absolutely be charged with running a red light to get out of the way of an ambulance and you're under no legal obligation to move out of the way if it involves breaking a traffic law.

I note in passing that Rule 219 doesn't say what you say it does; instead, it says the driver must comply "with all traffic signs".  Moreover, there is no legal tag appended to that rule, as there is in Rule 220, which means there's no statute that informs the rule: it is merely good guidance, and like other bits of the Highway Code that don't express statute law, may be ignored at your own risk.  So as I read it, you may (and arguably should) move across the stop line, exercising all necessary caution, far enough to let the emergency vehicle pass.

@Sneftel, here in Scotland (and probably elsewhere) blue-light drivers prefer not to bully other road users by using the horn in such a situation.  The obstructing vehicle may be able to see a hazard not visible to the emergency responder, or they may overreact and put themselves in danger. I don't know of emergency vehicles with loudspeakers, but if they exist I would expect they would similarly accept the other driver's judgement of what's a safe action (perhaps privately expressing frustration).

@MadHatter, is an automated traffic signal specifically excluded from the definition of "traffic signs" in your quote?  (I agree that facilitating the passage of an emergency responder is a reasonable defence to any infringement, assuming there's no other non-infringing alternative apart from continuing to obstruct).

@TobySpeight I do not have any informed opinion on whether a traffic signal is a traffic sign within the meaning of the Rule.  I'd guess that it was, but it doesn't affect the meat of my argument, which is that the Rule doesn't express a statutory provision, and so is not mandatory, but instead falls into that category of Highway Code advice the contravention of which may, in the event of an incident, give rise to a finding of liability.  My note about the rule being misquoted was merely a pointer to the need for precision when quoting official guidance.

@TobySpeight I’m not sure what you thought the thrust of my question was, but that wasn’t it. I was trying to ascertain whether the driver had received what amounted to an explicit order from the emergency responder, or whether their actions would have been on their own initiative.

@Sneftel: I think Toby Speight was giving an indirect answer to your question - you're asking "did the emergency responder give the driver an order", and the answer is basically "(in Scotland at least) emergency responders don't do that" - i.e. "no" :)

@MadHatter the guidance only being guidance doesn't mean the law can be ignored. If the light is red, it is illegal to cross it without being told to by the police (or being an emergency vehicle). Full stop. https://www.askthe.police.uk/faq/?id=4c316a8a-13db-eb11-bacb-0022483f57c9

@Tim  I beg you to read what I wrote.  I'm not saying the Highway Code in its entirety doesn't say that red lights are mandatory (unless directed by a policeman, etc.).  I'm saying Rule 219 doesn't say that.

@MadHatter I was more disagreeing with your conclusion: “ law, may be ignored at your own risk. So as I read it, you may (and arguably should) move across the stop line, exercising all necessary caution, far enough to let the emergency vehicle pass.”. I don’t think that it’s true.

@Tim that's a bit of a selective quote.  What I said was "like other bits of the Highway Code that don't express statute law, [it] may be ignored at your own risk", which I still maintain is correct for rule 219, as it has no statutory tag attached, and therefore doesn't summarise a point of statute.  As my comment is clear, that's just my read of rule 219.  I say nothing about anything the rest of the Code has to say about red lights, and the statutory basis thereof.

switzerland
Yes.
While it's the last of all options to consider, it seems legal to cross the line when an emergency vehicle approaches from behind, but only as far as absolutely necessary (e.g move in front of another lane instead of just crossing the intersection), as this news report suggests.
The relevant law (Article 16) suggests that "Wenn es zur sofortigen Freigabe der Fahrbahn unerlässlich ist, müssen die Fahrzeugführer mit der gebotenen Vorsicht auf das Trottoir ausweichen" (If it is necessary, in order to immediately free the lane, the drivers must, with the recommended caution, draw onto the sidewalk). So this is the preferred solution, if possible.
When you get a ticket from e.g. an automatic red-light camera, you can object and usually get the fine revoked. The emergency vehicle will likely be visible in the image and/or also be flashed for crossing the red light.

@SomeoneSomewhereSupportsMonica You are right,  this was a translation error. And it made the answer probably a bit better than even desired...

The emergency vehicle will also trigger the red light camera, and when reviewing the tickets to go out, should trigger a diligent worker to put both tickets into a separate review or right to disposal.

@Trish "Dilligent" might be a hard-to-find requirement. Maybe things are better in Europe, YMMV

@MindwinRememberMonica AFAIK, the system even might flag such incidents in some towns.

@Trish Oh, awesome. The wonders of the world on the other side of the narrow ocean.

germany

Straßenverkehrs-Ordnung (StVO):
§ 36 Zeichen und Weisungen der Polizeibeamten
(1) Die Zeichen und Weisungen der Polizeibeamten sind zu befolgen. Sie gehen allen anderen Anordnungen und sonstigen Regeln vor, entbinden den Verkehrsteilnehmer jedoch nicht von seiner Sorgfaltspflicht.
[...]
§ 38 Blaues Blinklicht und gelbes Blinklicht
(1) Blaues Blinklicht zusammen mit dem Einsatzhorn darf nur verwendet werden, wenn höchste Eile geboten ist, um Menschenleben zu retten oder schwere gesundheitliche Schäden abzuwenden, eine Gefahr für die öffentliche Sicherheit oder Ordnung abzuwenden, flüchtige Personen zu verfolgen oder bedeutende Sachwerte zu erhalten.
Es ordnet an:
„Alle übrigen Verkehrsteilnehmer haben sofort freie Bahn zu schaffen“.

Translation:

Road Traffic Regulations (StVO):
§ 36 Signs and instructions from police officers
(1) The signs and instructions of police officers must be obeyed. They take precedence over all other instructions and other rules, but do not release road users from their duty of care.
[...]
§ 38 Blue flashing light and yellow flashing light
(1) Blue flashing lights together with the emergency horn may only be used if extreme haste is required to save human life or prevent serious damage to health, to avert a danger to public safety or order, to pursue fleeing persons or to preserve important material assets.
It orders:
"All other road users must give way immediately".

That means that when "ordered" by emergency services via light and sirens, you are to make room, ignoring all other traffic laws, only making sure nobody else gets harmed.
So yes, running a red light is allowed, assuming you do it slowly, carefully and don't endanger anyone else. Normally, you creep into the intersection at walking speed and when the emergency vehicle has passed, you go back, just as slowly.
§ 35 clarifies who is allowed to use special privileges, but it is two pages long, I am not going to quote it. It contains what you would expect it to, police, rescue, fire fighter, military, customs, civilian services for important infrastructure, like fixing gas leaks or electrical problems etc. Quite frankly, nobody is questioning a siren and flashing lights. They will have a permit.

And just from personal experience: you will regularly see cars creeping over red lights, onto sidewalks or laws, going over grass or bike lanes, to make room for emergency vehicles. If an emergency vehicle wants to go through, everything else becomes secondary and nobody will complain about you breaking any rules.
Other people accepting it as normal doesn't mean anything for the legality of it, but it is not only legal, it is widely known and accepted to be legal.

I can’t see the connection you’re drawing between those two sections. It sounds like you’re saying that a fire truck’s siren is legally a police officer ordering drivers to give way.

@Sneftel, "police" means in this context "police or other authorized personnel as enumerated previously." §36 is relevant because it stresses the need for caution by the motorist.

@o.m. I can't see where you're quoting from. The previous section explicitly refers to police and firefighters separately. Which section has that enumeration?

@Sneftel paragraph 35. nvoigt explained why it is pointless to quote it in full; https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stvo_2013/__35.html

@o.m. But that section doesn't define "police" to include other emergency responders.

@Sneftel, it defines that the other services have Sonderrechte just like the police. That does not make them the police.

But the other sections don’t hinge on that status. They don’t even mention it.

Side Note: If you don't clear the way or drive into the way to stop a rescue vehicle with active Sonderrechte, you could be prosecuted for duress. If your act results in a delay that leads to a death, you could even be charged for that!

About the experience: The rescue vehicle will drive dangerously if you don't make way fast enough. There have been numerous occasions of RTWs colliding with drivers who did not make way or not fast enough or who, god behold, swerved to the wrong side (e.g. from left lane to the right instead of left)

Trish ist correct. Just for context, an "RTW" is an ambulance on emergency/rescue duty (compared to a "KTW", also an ambulance, but on transport duty for non-emergencies).

@nvoigt I’m still baffled by this. It doesn’t seem like o.m. has represented your reasoning correctly or coherently.

@Sneftel I think you are asking a little much in terms of coherency from a law that was written by someone who thought fit to include some weird first-person-roleplaying into it. Those are the laws we have, and they are interpreted exactly as I described. There are no court decisions, because those cases don't go to court. Every single page of advice will tell you the same. For example: https://www.malteser.de/aware/hilfreich/blaulicht-im-strassenverkehr-das-korrekte-verhalten.html . None of them can cite the actual law any better than I did.

And yes, I think o.m. presented it correctly, the incoherence is in the law, not their explanation.

@nvoigt One tip some site (maybe ADAC?) had was to take note of the number plate of the ambulance just to make sure you have something to show if and when the traffic light comes with automatic video surveillance. Might want to add that to the answer if you think it's helpful.

@Sneftel There actually is some caselaw, but in Germany, Caselaw is non-binding unless it is from the BGH, and no such case ever got there, because everybody will accept that a redlight infraction to make way for emergency vehicles is exigent circumstances and it is not warrented to take 200 bucks for the redlight when life is on the line. Remember that hindering rescue workers is actually a crime (StGB § 323 c Abs. 2), while a redlight infraction is just a fineable misdemeanor. With Nothilfe (emergency help) you can breach lesser laws to save life and limb (StGB § 32)

So the argumentation also could be "I provide emergency help by making way for the emergency vehicle, which is a total excuse for the redlight infraction. I also do not commit hindering or rescue workers by making way and follow the order of the StVO to make way for them."

ADAC (the major German automobile association) has a video on this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6YqGr7hC7A. Main takeaway: it is legal to run a red traffic light if this was necessary to make way for emergency services. They recommend recording the date and time, ideally also the license plate of the emergency vehicle, so that in case you do get a ticket, you can contest it. Btw, fines for impeding an emergency vehicle start at € 240, plus 2 points on the driver’s license, and suspension of the license for 1 month.

@Trish § 32 is about Notwehr (self-defense), which is only applicable when defending oneself or others against an unlawful attack. What you describe is close to § 34 (rechtfertigender Notstand): adequate acts with the aim of fending off an imminent threat to the life, limb, freedom, honor, property or any other legal good shall not be illegal if, assessing the conflicting interests, in particular the legal goods concerned and the risk to them, the protected good outweighs the affected one. IANAL, though.

@user149408 True, §34 also applies. Also: It's allowable to run a red light if you try to get a person to the hospital in your car under the same justifications.

england-and-wales
West Yorkshire Police have offered this (ahem) helpful guide.

What should I do if I am at a red traffic light and there is an emergency vehicle behind me trying to get through?
Rule 219 of The Highway Code states:
'You should look and listen for ambulances, fire engines, police,
doctors or other emergency vehicles using flashing blue, red or green
lights and sirens or flashing headlights, or Highways Agency Traffic
Officer and Incident Support vehicles using flashing amber lights.
When one approaches do not panic. Consider the route of such a vehicle
and take appropriate action to let it pass, while complying with all
traffic signs. If necessary, pull to the side of the road and stop,
but try to avoid stopping before the brow of a hill, a bend or narrow
section of road. Do not endanger yourself, other road users or
pedestrians and avoid mounting the kerb. Do not brake harshly on
approach to a junction or roundabout, as a following vehicle may not
have the same view as you.'
Therefore, as outlined above, if there is an emergency vehicle behind
you with its emergency warning signals on, it might be possible for
you to manoeuvre out of the way to allow it through. Ideally this
should be to the side of the road without encroaching into the main
area of the junction (see below). It should only be done when it is
safe to do so without putting yourself or other members of the public
in danger and it should only be done slowly and carefully.
If you do cross the stop line at the junction whilst the lights are on
red, you will commit the offence of contravening a red traffic light.
It's important to remember that in committing the offence (crossing
the stop line) the onus will be on you to provide evidence that you
did so to allow an emergency vehicle through. That may be considered
as mitigation, but there is no guarantee that it will be. If the
police decide to prosecute you for the offence and you choose to
challenge that decision, it will ultimately be a matter for a court to
decide.
WYP: Ask The Police

A registered solicitor gives us an indication of what is likely to occur if you offer this as your sole defence. In short, you'll still be found guilty of an offence and unless you were specifically directed to move, the fact that an emergency service vehicle was behind you won't normally count in lessening the sentence you receive.

...running a red light is what is referred to as an absolute offence
and mitigation rarely succeeds unless you were signalled by police to
cross the white line when light is red; or if you had no[t] option but
to move forward to avoid an accident or to give way to an ambulance.
Solicitor4All - Just Answer: Ask a Solicitor


That last quote does not say you'll probably fail in this specific case, giving way to an ambulance is explicitly given as an exception to the general rule.

@Aetol - Ah, now the law says that you can user the fact that you were asked to move by an ambulance or told to move by a policeman as effective mitigation. You'll still be found guilty of an offence though, because you absolutely did commit an offence.

RTA 1988 s36 does not have any exceptions. I've no idea where the solicitor got that advice from.

@AndrewLeach - The law may be absolute, but from a 'public interest' perspective, no judge or jury is going to find someone guilty if the police explicitly told them where to drive, and a camera snapped them doing so. The CPS would decline to prosecute.

Note that he's not saying that the excuse will result in you being found not guilty. The mitigation bit happens afterwards.

@Richard In the scenario the solicitor raises of being prosecuted after a policeman directed you to commit the offence, I'd rather expect this to be brought up beforehand, in a motion to throw out the charges on grounds of entrapment - not merely afterwards in mitigation! (Note that entrapment isn't a defence per se in the UK like the US; instead it's a basis to ask the court to dismiss the charges against you for being an abuse of process, even though you still technically committed the offence.)

@MarkAmery - The point here is that an absolute offense is one where you're found guilty on the face of the evidence. The 'a copper told me to do it' part is not a defence that can be used.

netherlands
No.  Article 50 of the traffic code only states that priority vehicles using sirens must be given priority (right of way). This does not include an exemption to violate other rules when giving way.
(As a practical matter, it appears common to not prosecute minor violations.)

Does the Netherlands not use an automated for prosecuting this sort of thing? As the comments to the question mention, in the UK we would automatically get a letter in the post + have to defend ourselves.

I'd think a red light camera photo of your vehicle with an ambulance behind it would make for a short defense. But, yes, still a hassle.

Do you have a source to back that up? This seems to match the UK ruling but be in contradiction to the continental European rules cited in various other answers.

@JonCuster: I'd hope that cars move away before the ambulance is so close as to be on the photo (and until they have nosed their way to the actual crossing, the light may be green). But at least in Germany, emergency vehicles using blue light + siren are thoroughly documented, so it is in any case fairly easy for the authorities to verify the claim that one had to give way. And in any case the photo should show cars at typical out-of-the-way position compared to "normal" red light violations.

@JonCuster you don't know Dutch traffic courts I see. The only way to get out from under a traffic ticket is to prove that it wasn't your car (thus fake/stolen plates on another make and model car basically).

@Tim: No, Dutch courts made short shrift of that. The law states that only authorized people may prosecute ("Officier van Justitie", OvJ) and automated systems are neither authorized nor people. However, automated systems can and do send letters inviting you to add information before prosecution starts.

@quarague: These types of rules aren't standardized, so the idea of "contintental European rules" simply makes no sense.

@quarague A court recently went along with exactly this defense, following an automatic sanction based on a red light camera  (case ECLI:NL:RBNHO:2023:14079). The court decided that this was an exceptional situation and that a sanction would be unreasonable.

finland
Tieliikennelaki 10 §:

Tienkäyttäjän on liikenteenohjauslaitteella osoitetusta
velvollisuudesta riippumatta annettava hälytysääni- ja -valomerkkejä
antavalle hälytysajoneuvolle ... esteetön kulku. Tällöin on
tarvittaessa siirryttävä sivuun tai pysähdyttävä.

Rough translation: Road user must provide unimpeded path forward for an emergency vehicle giving sound and light signals regardless of what is indicated by traffic lights, traffic signs or road markings.
However, the moves have to be necessary for giving the emergency vehicles a way past you.

israel
Depends
Regulation 93 states that when security (emergency) vehicle approaches, drivers must give right of way and stop to the right, afar from intersections.
As a practical matter however, it is not possible in most cases to let an ambulance through traffic without crossing the intersection boundaries and drivers can do that, as long as they do that carefully and without harming anyone else.
Not giving way to an emergency vehicle is a violation. Crossing on red to let an ambulance go is also a violation. A driver must chose which one they'd be able to defend themselves better against, and usually crossing the red light without causing any other harm would be the preferred option rather than letting someone die in an ambulance stuck in traffic.
For police (including military police, city police and road management companies), there's also regulation 23, which requires compliance. So if a police car demands the driver gives way by crossing into the intersection on red - the driver must comply.

germany, as addition to nvoigt's answer
Answer for the video linked in a comment (snapshot below) and assuming the siren is actually on (which is plausible but the gif video doesn't have sound, and in Germany the Sonderrechte-magic requires blue flash light and siren)


Are the driver's actions [staying where they are until green, then starting] legal in this situation

NO - they need to immediately make way - unless the fire truck had their siren off. In that case they behaved as they should.

is the driver required by law to enter the intersection on red in order to make way for the emergency vehicle?

Also NO since there is no necessity: they have sufficient space before even violating the stopping line to move sideways and forward so that the fire truck can pass.
(If there is really no other possibility to let the emergency vehicle pass, then yes they may have moved into the crossing)

Details:

Since the car is stopped at the stop line, they cannot move out of the way without entering the intersection

For most cars at most traffic lights this is not true.
(Fully-grown trucks and cars with trailer may have more difficulties, though. Also, e.g. construction sites may restrict the space where one can put the car. But yes, you'd be supposed to fold in your mirror and e.g. move up a tunnel's safety strip "pavement" if that's what is needed)
First, one is supposed to stop well before the holding line and subsequent cars are supposed to leave adequate distance as well. One of the reasons for this is to have maneuvering space to move the car sideways (really squeeze to the side of the lane or go on the sidewalk or embankment) in order to give way for emergency vehicles.
Consider the video: The green car on the 1st lane has (in an exemplary manner) left plenty of space even before the stopping line. They could thus have used it to move far to the right, which would have given the fire truck sufficient space to pass. Yes, the red car on the 2nd lane may have helped as well by moving further to the left.
(BTW, note that the fire truck is labelled in German: Feuerwehr)
Second, intersections with traffic light are on purpose designed with space between the stop line and the actual traffic light which in turn is placed well before the actual intersection begins:
 source
Also, the general ban on stopping and parking near crossings means that there are no parked cars keeping you from entering the sidewalk or embankment.
Thus, in case one nevertheless finds oneself without sufficient space before the stop line, there is the additional safety zone even before the actual traffic light.
In Germany, violating the stop line alone is a really minor thing (as long as noone is endangered). Violating the red traffic light happens when crossing the actual post with the signal. And that is still well before entering the crossing. (Side note: automatic traffic light violation cameras usually record several levels of violation, and distinguish stopping line violation from red light violation/actually entering the crossing. In the situation discussed here, the timestamps would also show that the violation did not happen at speed but by a very slow car, plus possibly the position of vehicles indicating that they form a passing lane)
Since fines need to be proportionate to the offense, the catalogue of traffic fines at the KBA may be used as convenient surrogate to compare the seriousness of different violations.
Not giving way for an emergency vehicle with flashing blue light + siren on is above red traffic light violations that did not actually endanger someone.

138600    Sie unterließen es, einem Einsatzfahrzeug mit eingeschaltetem blauen Blinklicht und Einsatzhorn sofort freie Bahn zu schaffen.
You failed to immediately give way to an emergency vehicle with its blue flashing lights and siren switched on.
§ 38 Abs. 1, § 49 StVO; § 24 Abs. 1, 3 Nr. 5, § 25 StVG; 135 BKat;  § 4 Abs. 1 BKatV
category A; 2 points + 240,00 € fine + 1 month without driver's license

141211 Sie hielten nicht an der Haltlinie (Zeichen 294).
You did not stop at the stopping line (sign 294)
§ 41 Abs. 1 iVm Anlage 2, § 49 StVO; § 24 Abs. 1, 3 Nr. 5 StVG;
154 BKat
10,00 € fine

137600 Sie missachteten das Rotlicht der Lichtzeichenanlage.
You disregarded the red light at the traffic lights.
§ 37 Abs. 2, § 49 StVO; § 24 Abs. 1, 3 Nr. 5 StVG; 132 BKat
category A; 1 point + 90,00 € fine

137618 Sie missachteten das Rotlicht der Lichtzeichenanlage. Die Rotphase
dauerte bereits länger als 1 Sekunde an.
You disregarded the red light at the traffic lights. The red phase
lasted longer than 1 second.
§ 37 Abs. 2, § 49 StVO; § 24 Abs. 1, 3 Nr. 5, § 25 StVG; 132.3 BKat;
§ 4 Abs. 1 BKatV
category A; 2 points + 200,00 € fine + 1 month without driver's license

for comparison, this one is triggered even without any emergency vehicle being around, as soon as the traffic slows down to walking speed (but this happens far from a traffic light):
111600 Sie bildeten auf einer Autobahn oder Außerortsstraße keine
vorschriftsmäßige *) Gasse zur Durchfahrt von Polizei- oder
Hilfsfahrzeugen, obwohl der Verkehr stockte.
You did not form a lane on a highway or out-of-town road
lane for the passage of police or emergency vehicles, even though traffic was at a stagnated.
§ 11 Abs. 2, § 49 StVO; § 24 Abs. 1, 3 Nr. 5, § 25 StVG; 50 BKat;
§ 4 Abs. 1 BKatV
category A; 2 points + 200,00 € fine + 1 month without driver's license

There are additional violations with increasing severity in case someone was endangered or the violation actually having caused an accident (for all of them).



Some legal opinions saying that red light may be violated in order to allow the emergency vehicle to pass as long as noone is endangered. Nevertheless, one should not go further than absolutely necessary (All in German):

https://www.gansel-rechtsanwaelte.de/schlagzeile/was-darf-man-um-dem-rettungswagen-platz-zu-machen, translation:

If an ambulance is approaching from behind and you have no possibility of driving to the side due to a narrow road or roadworks, you may even drive through a red light. Please note that you are not allowed to cross the entire intersection, but only the stop line. This must also be done in such a way that no other road users are endangered. So drive slowly up to the red light, watch out for crossing traffic and position your vehicle at the junction so that the ambulance can pass.
If a camera was installed in the traffic light system that was triggered by your maneuver, you are usually off the hook. As soon as you hear a blue flashing light in combination with a siren, all vehicles must make way! If you receive a fine notice some time later, you can state that you swerved to avoid an ambulance. Ideally, you should be able to provide the registration number of the emergency vehicle, organization, time and date so that the fining authority can check what happened. However, the proceedings against you should generally be discontinued - nor can you be required to pay a fine.


https://www.anwalt.de/rechtstipps/rettungswagen-im-einsatz-ueberholen-davonrasen-und-andere-verkehrsverstoesse-erlaubt_159835.html, translation:

What happens if you are at a traffic light, an ambulance comes up behind you and you have no room to pull over? Can you just drive through the red light? The most important basic rule in this situation is that you must not endanger other road users!
In principle, you are allowed to drive through the traffic lights in this case. However, it is advisable to only drive as far as necessary over the stop line and not necessarily into the intersection. Once you have let the emergency vehicle through, it is best to wait behind the traffic lights for the next green phase or, if possible, drive back behind the stop line.




All translations by deepl with some manual help by me

Translations are okay, no need to correct them.

"one is supposed to stop well before the holding line". No. The line is named holding line for a reason - it's the line where a driver has to stop their vehicle at the latest. While a driver can indeed stop well before the holding line, there is no rule that supposes them to do so. In practice a lot of drivers stop rather close to the holding line.

Also, while some intersections indeed have ample space between stopping line and pedestrian crossing, the main intention of this space is not maneuvering room, but to increase visibility of the intersection (head doesn't need to move as much to view the complete intersection) and to provide buffer space so a car that fails to stop in time for the stopping line doesn't drive into the pedestrian crossing. It is a fairly recent design development, and you can still find a lot of intersections where the pedestrian crossing starts right after the stopping line.

@Inconspicuousseagull "Well" means something about 1 meter in common understanding of drivers (see the photo of the intersection, the black car is about that from the line while the white is like... 60 cm). The green car is about 4, so wastes space but that is not an infraction.

@Inconspicuousseagull: yes, using the safety zone for maneuvering is a collateral advantage if you like. But it is available in case it is needed. Even if there is a pedestrian crossing, also pedestrians are supposed to help making way for the emergency vehicle. Also, sure it is best and easiest to drive forward to the side, and personally I'd nose my way forward - it's both faster and safer in the described situation where everyone will tend to move forward and sideways and does not expect backward movement.

OTOH, 1m lengthwise does allow quite some sideways movement. And while I cannot recall what the official instructions for the holding line were, I'm sure many years back when I took my driver's license we were explicitly told to leave maneuvering space because some sideways movement may be needed  not to stop nose to tail to leave emergency vehicles pass - both for intersections and in traffic jam (where this is in addition to forming the emergency lane). As a side note, space before holding line and between cars is easier to judge for the crossing lanes - which looks easy and spacey...

... compared to typical lengthwise parking situations where more than a full car width of sideways movement is needed. Much more than would be the required contribution of one lane for the emergency vehicle to pass.

hungary
The question comes up relatively often in the press and both the police and the paramedics always stress that yes, you are supposed to do so, with the proper caution and attention to others around you, of course. The Highway Code (KRESZ) says:

"42. § (1) [...] minden helyzetben elsőbbséget kell adni, és
akadálytalan továbbhaladását – félrehúzódással és a szükséghez képest
megállással – lehetővé kell tenni."
"[...] shall be given priority in all situations and shall be allowed
to proceed unhindered by pulling over and stopping as necessary."

This is the main instruction and seems to trump everything else. The rest is anecdotal, but during all the decades of driving mostly in the capital, Budapest, where such situations can happen relatively frequently, it never occurred to me to do otherwise. This is just so obvious. I would also expect a driver failing to do so to be chastised immediately by a fierce use of the horn or the PA system of the emergency vehicle.

france
Yes. You must run the red light, if no other choice.
According to the article R415-12 of the Traffic Code (translation and emphasised text is mine):

En toutes circonstances, tout conducteur est tenu de céder le passage aux véhicules d'intérêt général prioritaires annonçant leur approche par l'emploi des avertisseurs spéciaux prévus pour leur catégorie.


In all circumstances, every driver must yield the right of way to emergency vehicles announcing their approach by using the special warning signals provided for their category

Every possible doubt in the interpretation by the general population is removed by this entry in an official FAQ:

Suis-je sanctionné si je grille un feu pour laisser passer un véhicule prioritaire ?
Non. […]


Am I penalized if I run a red light to let an emergency vehicles pass?
No.  […]


denmark
Yes.
The Danish police has published the following guide:

DET SKAL DU GØRE NÅR DU HØRER EN UDRYKNING
Når et køretøj kører udrykningskørsel, fx fordi det skal frem til en alvorlig trafikulykke, eller skal overflytte en kritisk patient fra et sygehus til et andet, handler det om at få hjælpen frem så hurtigt som muligt. Hvert minut er dyrebart og kan betyde forskellen mellem liv eller død.
Så snart du bliver opmærksom på et udrykningskøretøj, skal du give plads. [...]
[...]Det er tilladt at køre frem mod rødt lys, hvis det gøres for at give plads til udrykningskøretøjet. Dog skal du først sikre dig, at du ikke er til fare for andre.

Translation:

What to Do When You Hear an Emergency Vehicle
When a vehicle is responding to an emergency, such as heading to a serious traffic accident or transferring a critical patient from one hospital to another, it's crucial to get help to the scene as quickly as possible. Every minute is precious and can mean the difference between life and death. [...]
[...] It is permitted to move forward against a red light if it is done to make room for the emergency vehicle. However, you must first ensure that you are not endangering others.

There is no direct allowance for this in the Danish Traffic Act ("Færdselsloven") or the relevant ministerial order, but it falls under the Penal Code ("Straffeloven") §14:

En handling, der ellers ville være strafbar, straffes ikke, når den var nødvendig til afværgelse af truende skade på person eller gods, og lovovertrædelsen måtte anses for at være af forholdsvis underordnet betydning.

Translation:

An act that would otherwise be punishable is not subject to punishment if it was necessary to avert an imminent danger to person or property, and the offense must be considered of relatively minor significance.

Or perhaps, given the published instructions from the Danish police, one could argue that it falls under the Traffic Act's §4 section 2:

Trafikanter skal efterkomme de anvisninger for færdslen, som gives af politiet eller andre, som transportministeren har bemyndiget til at regulere færdslen [...]

Translation:

Road users must comply with the traffic instructions given by the police or other persons authorized by the Minister of Transport to regulate traffic [...]


austria
Yes
https://ris.bka.gv.at/eli/bgbl/1960/159/P26/NOR40245676

(5) Alle Straßenbenützer haben einem herannahenden Einsatzfahrzeug
Platz zu machen. Kein Lenker eines anderen Fahrzeuges darf unmittelbar
hinter einem Einsatzfahrzeug nachfahren oder, außer um ihm Platz zu
machen, vor ihm in eine Kreuzung einfahren.

In English:

(5) All road users must give way to an approaching emergency vehicle.
No driver of another vehicle may drive directly behind an emergency
vehicle or enter an intersection in front of it, except to make way
for it.


Further sources for this interpretation of this somewhat oddly worded law: https://www.roteskreuz.at/oberoesterreich/freistadt/news/aktuelles/ein-rettungswagen-kommt-selten-alleine https://www.samariter-favoriten.at/samariterbund-richtiges-verhalten-bei-herannahen-von-einsatzfahrzeugen/

The other day I witnessed a police car with lights on (no sirens) stop behind a motorcyclist staying on red. The police car used the horn to attract the attention of the motorcyclist and have him move away (by crossing the white line).
This in Bulgaria. Not sure about the letter of the law but I've seen many times people give way by entering the intersection and I've done that once to give way to an ambulance.
The relevant part of the law "Закон за Движение по Пътищата (ЗДвП)" /Law for moving on the roads/ is:

Чл. 104. (1) При приближаване на моторно превозно средство със специален режим на движение водачите на останалите пътни превозни средства са длъжни да освободят достатъчно място на пътното платно, а при необходимост и да спрат, за да осигурят безпрепятствено преминаване както на сигнализиращото, така и на съпровожданите от него превозни средства.

It only states that one is required to make way but no really specific.
But there is a court case I found about speeding. My reading of it is that in general speeding can be excused when absolutely necessary. Although in that specific case it was decided that the decision to speed was not correct.

автомобилът, за който касаторът твърди, че е линейка с включени звуков и светлинен сигнали, е в такава близост до неговия автомобил, която показва несвоевременно изпълнение на задължението по чл.104, ал.1 от ЗДвП. Именно защото е избрал неправилен начин да даде предимство на автомобила със специален режим на движение, С. не може да бъде  освободен от отговорност за управление на собственото си МПС с превишена скорост.

Basically court decided that the driver had plenty of opportunity to go to the right lane as everybody else instead of speeding forward. There is nothing in the decision that states speeding (or other) rules take precedence over the requirement to give way.
This makes me think that overall the general interpretation of the law would be that you should give way but in a reasonable way and you may be fined for taking a wrong decision. Although I think it is unlikely to be fined for staying on the crossroad in practice and might be easier to defend such a decision.
For more I guess you need to speak with a lawyer.

The OP’s question was specifically about the letter of the law, not de facto local customs.

In most of the world, police instructions override any other traffic laws.

@Sneftel, the question is "are you allowed". He mentions law in the body of the question but doesn't specifically ask only about "law". Often times law and what you're actually allowed differs. But I'll also add a little expansion of the answer about law.

This whole site is about the law - it's literally the name of the site - so it's not necessary for every question to spell that out.

@akostadinov the language used in art. 104 is absolutely unequivocal, as far as I understand Bulgarian (and I pretty much do). You are required to move out of the way and/or stop, whatever is needed to let the emergency vehicle pass, no other conditions attached. The text above and below 104 does not place any other decision burden either. The cited court case is a weak attempt of a blatant abuse of 104 that does not hold water and the court expectedly stamped the appeal "ad usum in latrine".

@fraxinus, mostly agree with you, though limitations are always applicable. If you move out of the way but hit somebody, then I doubt you will easily get away with it. For sure with such a traffic rule a lot of common sense needs to be applied.

@akostadinov get away - hardly, reduce the consequences - there are examples in the media.
